# Android permissions request ignored. App can not run

Tags: android

Working on an android project and everything was fine until today. All of a sudden, permissions requests are ignored and app can not run. When I check App permission through Application in Settings, no permission allowed. I have to manually allow all permissions to let the app run.

Samsung S7 running API 24.

Why is this?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.xyz.abc">
<uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<application
    android:name=".AbcApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme">
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <!-- Splash Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- MainActivity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen"
        />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.ItemsInCategoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.PaymentMethodActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.ProductDetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".chat.ChatActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.SellerProfileActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.MyProfileDetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.AboutMeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.SearchRadiusActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.FriendInviteActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.ResetPasswordActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <service
        android:name=".aws.network.NetworkService"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="uploading" />
    <service
        android:name=".service.SocketIOClientManagerService"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="uploading" />
    <service
        android:name="com.xgnetwork.hardwarepolling.LocationOnlyPollingService"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:process=":abc_location_polling" />
    <service
        android:name="com.xgnetwork.hardwarepolling.WifiScanningService"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:process=":abc_wifi_polling" />

    <receiver android:name=".location.receivers.UploadLocationReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name=".location.receivers.WifiReceiver" />

    <receiver android:name=".receiver.braintree.SellerApplicationApprovedReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.braintree.SellerApplicationDeclinedReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.braintree.SellerApplicationReceivedReceiver" />

    <receiver android:name=".receiver.sms.SmsDeliveredReceiver" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" /><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled" android:value="true"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Are you requesting the dangerous permissions at runtime? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704

Comment: no. The permissions are all requested through AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Have a read through the accepted answer on the linked duplicate.